# How can I hide an API that includes custom typedefs in its interface behind the PIMPL idiom?

Tags: c++, typedef, dependency-management, pimpl-idiom

I have a very frustrating situation where I am trying to separate my software from a compile-time dependency on a vendor provided API. The typical way to do this would be to implement a "wrapper" class around the API that uses the PIMPL idiom to hide the vendor provided API entirely behind an opaque pointer.

For example...

**wrapper.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper();
    ~Wrapper();

    // Function that uses vendor API in its implementation
    void Function1();
private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};
```

**wrapper.cpp**

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vendor/api.h>

struct Wrapper::Impl {
    void Function1() {

        // Vendor API call hidden entirely within the private implementation
        VendorApiFunction1();
    }
};

Wrapper::Wrapper() : m_impl(std::make_unique<Impl>()) {}
Wrapper::~Wrapper() = default;

// Forward call to the private implementation
Wrapper::Function1() {
    m_impl->Function1();
}
```

The issue is that the vendor provided API defines some global `typedef`s that it uses in its interface. Which makes the declaration of `Function1()` in `wrapper.h` look like this:

```
void Function1(CUSTOM_API_TYPE input);
```

This input is then passed down into the implementation where it is ultimately passed to the vendor provided API function.

This creates a very frustrating problem... Since `typedef`s cannot be forward declared this now forces me to add `#include <vendor/api.h>` to the top of `wrapper.h` just to make `CUSTOM_API_TYPE` available. Adding the vendor header to `wrapper.h` then imposes a compile-time dependency on the vendor provided API for all clients of `wrapper.h` which is EXACTLY what I was using the PIMPL idiom to avoid...

Is there any standard way of dealing with this kind of situation?

Comment: Maybe redefine the `typedef` yourself? If it exactly matches the one provided by `<vendor/api.h>`, this could be an option, right?

Comment: Technically yes, but that just feels like such a brittle solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap `CUSTOM_API_TYPE` in my own type and translate it inside my wrapper.

That might create a lot of boiler-plate code, but that's the way to go if you wish to hide the implementation details.

Example :

**WRAPPER.H**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

struct MyCustomInput {
  int param1;
  int param2;
};

class Wrapper {
public:
    Wrapper();
    ~Wrapper();

    // Function that uses vendor API in its implementation
    void Function1(MyCustomInput input);
private:
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};
```

**WRAPPER.CPP**

```
#include "wrapper.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vendor/api.h>

struct Wrapper::Impl {
    void Function1(CUSTOM_API_TYPE implType) {

        // Vendor API call hidden entirely within the private implementation
        VendorApiFunction1(implType);
    }
};

Wrapper::Wrapper() : m_impl(std::make_unique<Impl>()) {}
Wrapper::~Wrapper() = default;

// Forward call to the private implementation
Wrapper::Function1(MyCustomInput input) {
  CUSTOM_API_TYPE implType;
  // That example is a 1:1 conversion of parameters, but you can ease the
  // programmer's life a little bit by hiding the API details
  implType.param1 = input.param1;
  implType.param2 = input.param2;
  m_impl->Function1(implType);
}
```

Comment: I made my example use a `struct` but that could also be a class.

Comment: That seems reasonable... but still leaves the question of what to do about function pointers used in callbacks. Theres some typedefs in the api like `typedef (void*)(API_CALLBACK)(CUSTOM_API_TYPE arg1, int arg2)`

Comment: Not 100% sure if the syntax is correct there but you get the idea lol

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Don't worry, I'm not that sure either, I haven't compiled my example.

I'll update my answer to add an example on how to hide a callback.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 Hum, I realized that I don't know enough of the original implementation to provide a working example, but you can look at [that article](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/manual/html/callbacks.html) to help you with callbacks. But the general idea stays : provide the programmer with your types, hide the conversion from your type to the implementation type in your code.